# Как обеспечить работоспособность конструкций типа Ship.Attack().Ship;?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как обеспечить работоспособность конструкций типа `Ship.Attack().Ship;` вместо `Ship.Attack(Ship);` где вместо класса Ship объекты этого класса, а функция Attack() реализует изменения второго объекта перемеными первого: _hp второго объекта уменьшаются на _force первого в одной функции или двух перегруженных одноимённых функций. Зачем это? Хочу, мне безумно нравится сахарность такой конструкции. В чём проблема? Как передать функции переменую второго объекта `Attack().Ship` да ещё с возможностью изменить приватную переменную (т.е. должна сработать одномённая функция у второго объекта).

Comment: В упор не вижу, чем такая конструкция лучше/красивше совершенно понятной конструкции `ship1.Attack(ship2)`. Я бы понял, если бы вы, например, переопределили что-нибудь из математики и атаку записывали как `ship1 * ship2` или `ship1 / ship2`. Вот такое и выглядит короче и реализовать просто.

Comment: А цепочечные конструкции имели бы смысл, если бы, например, одно судно могло атаковать сразу несколько, но и тогда это бы выглядело примерно так: `ship1.Attack().On(ship2).On(ship3)`, да и то непонятно, почему не `Attack(ship2).Attack(ship3)`

Comment: @МаксимФисман Вопрос не понял, смотрите ответ aepot, он там более подробно концепцию развил )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конкретно то что вы хотите сделать, невозможно. Потому что после точки указывается только член класса. Туда нельзя синтаксически засунуть локальную переменную.

Но не в одной атаке же смысл.

Предлагаю немного другое.

```cs
ship1.Target(ship2).Attack();
```

Такая конструкция позволит сначала взять цель, и затем только атаковать. Ну и здесь уже есть смысл в такой конструкции, так как после взятия цели можно выполнить не только атаку.

```cs
ship1.Target(ship2).Follow(); // следовать за целью
ship1.Target(ship2).Avoid(); // убегать от цели
```

Далее там можно стрелять из ГК, пускать торпеды, на что фантазии хватит. А реализуется такое достаточно просто.

```cs
public class Ship
{
    public Ship CapturedTarget { get; private set; }

    public Ship Target(Ship target)
    {
        CapturedTarget = target;
        return this;
    }

    public Ship Attack()
    {
        if (CapturedTarget is null)
            throw new NullReferenceException($"{nameof(CapturedTarget)} was null");

        // ... атаковать цель

        return this;
    }
}
```

Возврат значением из метода текущего класса позволяет ставить точки бесконечно. Это называется [Fluent Interface](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). На эту тему много всякого понаписано, поищите, почитайте. Скорее всего понимание того, как строяться Fluent интерфейсы, вам и позволит понять, что можно сделать, а что нельзя.

```cs
ship1.Target(ship2).Follow().Target(ship3).Attack().Avoid();
```

Comment: Спасибо всем, ответ принят. Не получится без извращений - тоже ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Синтаксис языка такого не позволит.